# Creating and sending SOAP message in Java

Tags: java, web-services, soap, soapui

How do I create a Soap message/envelope with the following content in Java and send it.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:cat="http://www.someurl.com/Catalogue/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <cat:GetRecordByField>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <cat:fieldName>Image</cat:fieldName>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <cat:value>10076GB.jpg</cat:value>
      </cat:GetRecordByField>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I have checked above message with SOAPUI and getting the correct response and now need to use JAVA to retrieve and process the response.

Update:

I have managed to generate following message, however it is not in the same format and is not acceptable.

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <cat:GetRecordByField xmlns:cat="http://quoteCompany.com">
            <cat:fieldName xmlns:cat="something">Image</cat:fieldName>
            <cat:value xmlns:cat="something1">10076GB.jpg</cat:value>
        </cat:GetRecordByField>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

I followed this tutorial: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/JDK-6/SendingaSOAPMessage.htm

Answer (score 0):

Use a webservice engine, like Axis, Artix etc. You can generate the code from SOAPui itself.